# Gambler's Ruin Problem: Finding a probability given specific duration, starting balance, and ending balance

Tags: probability, gambling

I am working on Grimmet's *Probability and Random Processes* and encounter a problem of this style.

In a betting game, we start with a balance of \$k. For each turn, we bet \$1, and the winning probability is p. What is the probability that the ending balance will be \$n after d turns and that we never lose all money during the play?

My attempt was writing the winning probability as a recurrence relation $p_{n, d} = p\cdot p_{n-1, d-1} + q\cdot p_{n+1, d-1}$, but it does not seem solvable.

What might be the best way to approach this kind of problem? Thank you!

Comment: Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNrqCdslGi4&index=7&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo

Comment: @Alex Thank you! However, it seems that the video only worked on the winning probability without a specific duration given.

Comment: You might be right, since my computer doesn't have sound.  But I thought he did-- in fact, at 19:42, he has that exact formula on the board, that you wrote in your question.

Comment: @Alex Not really, the formula is different. For mine, d also varies, while his formula has a fixed d.